# Adding Calculations in Kendo Grid Column Template

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
# if (((data.Price1 - data.Price2) / data.Price2< 0.02)) { #
    <table class="bg-success">
        <tr>
            <td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>
            <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, 'n') || "0" #</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20px"><img title="Price2" /></td>
        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, 'n') || "0" #</td>
    </tr>
</table>
# } else { #
<table class="bg-danger">
    <tr>
        <td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>
        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, 'n') || "0" #</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20px"><img title="Price2" /></td>
        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, 'n') || "0" #</td>
    </tr>
</table>
# } #
```

Hello All,

Above is the kendo column template I have added, but I am getting invalid template error which I am assuming is due to the calculation I have added in the if condition. I need this calculation to do the column formatting. Please let me know what I am missing here or where I am going wrong here.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue but no avail. I have shared my full code below so please try with it and let me know if any concern.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
    <script>
        var products = [{
            ProductID: 11,
            ProductName: "Chai",
            Price1: 13.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 22,
            ProductName: "Chang",
            Price1: 19.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 33,
            ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 44,
            ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 55,
            ProductName: "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductID",
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: {
                                    type: "string"
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                sortable: true,
                dataBound: function (e) {

                },
                filterable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "ProductID", title: "ProductID" },
                    { field: "ProductName", title: "ProductName" },
                    {
                        title: "Temp",
                        template: '# if (((Price1 - Price2) / Price2< 0.02)) { #' +
                                  '<table class="bg-success">' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                        '<td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>' +
                                        '<td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, "n") || "0" #</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                     '   <td width="20px"><img title="Price2" alt="Price2" /></td>' +
                                      '  <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, "n") || "0" #</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                    '</table>' +
                                    '# } else { # ' +
                                    ' <table class="bg-danger">' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                        '<td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>' +
                                        '<td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, "n") || "0" #</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                        '<td width="20px"><img title="Price2" /></td>' +
                                        '<td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, "n") || "0" #</td>' +
                                    '</tr>' +
                                  '</table>' +
                                  ' # } # ',
                    },
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }

                ],
                editable: "inline"
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        .bg-success {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .bg-danger {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1: For column template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="priceColumnTemplate">
        # if (((Price1 - Price2) / Price2< 0.02)) { #
                                  <table class="bg-success">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>
                                        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, "n") || "0" #</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="20px"><img title="Price2" alt="Price2" /></td>
                                        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, "n") || "0" #</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    # } else { # 
                                     <table class="bg-danger">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="20px"><label title="Price1"></label></td>
                                        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price1, "n") || "0" #</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="20px"><img title="Price2" /></td>
                                        <td width="90%">#= kendo.toString(Price2, "n") || "0" #</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                   # } # 
    </script>
    <script>
        var products = [{
            ProductID: 11,
            ProductName: "Chai",
            Price1: 13.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 22,
            ProductName: "Chang",
            Price1: 19.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 33,
            ProductName: "Aniseed Syrup",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 44,
            ProductName: "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }, {
            ProductID: 55,
            ProductName: "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
            Price1: 1.0,
            Price2: 11.0,
        }];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "ProductID",
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: {
                                    type: "string"
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                sortable: true,
                dataBound: function (e) {

                },
                filterable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "ProductID", title: "ProductID" },
                    { field: "ProductName", title: "ProductName" },
                    {
                        title: "Temp",
                        template: kendo.template( $( '#priceColumnTemplate' ).html()),
                    },
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }

                ],
                editable: "inline"
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        .bg-success {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .bg-danger {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Jayesh, Thanks for your answer. But I have written the code kendo template as :`<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="priceColumnTemplate">` and in the columns definition: `{ title: 'Price Details', template: kendo.template( $( '#priceColumnTemplate' ).html() )`, but I guess it shouldn't make any difference. Let me try the way you have suggested.

Comment: I have tried and its works fine for me. In-addition I have also updated my above post for same.

Comment: Yes it works. Apparently I missed one of the # symbol at the end of if condition which was causing the issue. Thanks anyways. :)